# Do I need to file taxes or can I file taxes educational credit refund purpose with 1098T?

Tags: united-states, taxes, credit, education, tax-credit

I did not work at all but I received a 1098T for my online school. The 1098T has $12,070.04 on box 1 and $2,529.53 on box 5. I will like to know if I should file taxes with the 1098T only to get educational credit?

Comment: There are many factors that can influence the answer to this question. The IRS has an online app to help people determine if they need to file: You may want to try using it to answer your own question: https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/do-i-need-to-file-a-tax-return